Baking vertex AO for multiple objects Python Script
I want to bake AO to vertex colors for multiple objects. The script I got so far can only do one at object at a time. What approach could I take to solve this problem?
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
bpy.context.scene.cycles.bake_type = 'AO'
bpy.context.scene.render.bake.target = 'VERTEX_COLORS'
bpy.ops.object.bake(type='AO')

As an example this could be a car mesh that consists of six objects:
four wheels a car body and an engine and I want to bake AO for all objects in one go!

Use selected_objects in an operator override.
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
bpy.context.scene.cycles.bake_type = 'AO'
bpy.context.scene.render.bake.target = 'VERTEX_COLORS'

# Whatever sequence of objects you want to bake :
objects_to_bake = bpy.data.collections["BAKE ME"].all_objects 

with bpy.context.temp_override(selected_objects=objects_to_bake):
    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='AO')


Thank you for your quick reply!
Right now it bakes one item at a time which works fine but takes quite a long time! Is there any way to make the bake operation just do one bake for all of the objects at once to save time? Cheers!

Cheers. Unless you join the objects into one I'm afraid not, it's already going as fast as it can I think.

Alright, thank you! :)
